# How to unify command line arguments(Flags) for two different binaries in python

Tags: python, command-line-interface, flags

I have combined two binaries into one for comparison purpose.py file. The two binaries are doing the very similar work essentially but using two sets of CLI arguments. 
E.g.,

First python binary `Par`: `myPar -myParArgs_1 '1' -myParArgs_2 'a'`

Second cpp binary `Bin`: `myBin -myBinArgs_1 '1' -myBinArgs_2 'a'`

Currently, I'm using `argparse` module to specify `myPar` arguments. But I don't know how to deal with the 2nd binary.

Is there any way to unify these two, such that when I specify any CLI arguments, both binaries will do the same thing and finally can generate the comparison report.

E.g.,`myMain -myMainArgs_1 '1' -myMainArgs_2 'a'` will call both binaries with correct arguments respectively.

Comment: What exactly is a python binary?

Comment: A main function that can read CLI input and parse the input to get the output. I added 2nd binary into this main function by using `subprocess.check_call`, but I don't know how to let the 2nd binary do the same thing as 1st binary with given command.

Comment: Do you want them to do the same thing, or take the same arguments? If this is equivalent, then they are the same program. If not, then you should clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a third script, be it either python, bash or batch file (depending on OS) that takes the said argument set and calls each binary respectively in order.

In python it should look something like

```
from sys import argv
import subprocess
call_args = sys.argv[1:]  #first position is script name
subprocess.call(['myPar'] + call_args) 
subprocess.call(['myBin'] + call_args)
```

Answer (score 0):

A parent script can spawn others scripts using subprocess package. The most popular one is Popen and Call (Call is an application of Popen)

Link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

```
**(For example, @compare.py -------------------)**
import os
from subprocess import *

outputPar = Popen([r'C:\myPar.py', <your argument (flags)>], *shell=True,* stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE).communicate()
outputBin = Popen([r'C:\myBin.py', <your argument (flags)>], *shell=True,* stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE).communicate()
... process outputs ...
```

With a bit more comment:

1) Shell=True may not a good idea from security warning

> Warning : Passing shell=True can be a security hazard if combined with untrusted input. See the warning under Frequently Used Arguments for details. (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

2) regarding Popen.communicate(input=None) method, 
    Interact with process: Send data to stdin.  Read data from stdout
    and stderr, until end-of-file is reached.  Wait for process to
    terminate.  The optional input argument should be a string to be
    sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be sent to
    the child.

```
communicate() returns a tuple (stdout, stderr).

Note: The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this
method if the data size is large or unlimited.
```